# ABI for Apache modules

Tags: c++, apache

the apache executable compiles with four major set of headers/libs:
the apache header files themselves
apr-util and apr header files
the mpm system we are using (worker, prefork, event are three used on unix. windows, osx have others)

The modules also compile with the same set of headers.

Is it possible to compile a binary module for apache versions like one version for apache2.2 and another for apache2.4 and run it everywhere? We do not want to compile it for every combination of all the libraries(apr mpm) that can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need one binary per apache release.  Your module can query the MPM dynamically and shouldn't depend on one or another directly (ap_mpm_query).  apr and apr-utility have really good forward compatibility.